# USB audio acquisition device : 2 channels recording

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have an USB audio acquisition device ( 2 channels, 1 microphone per channel).
This device is connected  with an Iphone.

The aim is to design a program in Swift in order to store the data in a buffer and then in pcm arrays (one array per channel).

I tested the connection between the Iphone and the acqusition device using AVAudiosession object.
The IPhone recognises the device. (ios compatble according to the manufacturer)

The process don’t need to work in real time :

1) Data acquisition

2) Stop acquisition

3) Finally processing data stored in pcm arrays (note in a file)

But I must confess that I’m little bit lost…

Do I have to consider two channels or one channel (one frame with one sample per channel) ?

(For Example : audiosession.inputNumberOfChannels = 1 or 2 ?)

Do I have to use Audio Queue, Audio Units Objects or another object?

I carried out several investigations on the Internet but I'm lost...

I would appreciate if you can get me on track by giving me some tips.

Thanks a lot for you support !

Best regards.

Jeff

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOS Swift read PCM Buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39162519/ios-swift-read-pcm-buffer) or [check this](https://www.google.de/search?q=swift+record+pcm+audio+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=22acWIvlFMev8wfR07HIDg).

Comment: Hey Jeff, let me know if the question linked above by @shallowThought helps.  If it does, I will mark your question as a duplicate.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi JAL I had read the question linked by @shallowThough, it was helpful , however my main concern is how to connect the audio device with the iPhone , I tried with an AVAudiosession object but unsuccessfully so far. Thanks JAL